# Query fails after inserting into database (db_session not working) in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I faced the following error after running an insertion using SQLAlchemy:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 140671235118848 and this is thread id 140671365665408.
```

I am running this on an interactive python shell. I have the following code in /app/database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/test.db', convert_unicode=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
```

And my model is in app/models/product/**init**.py

So I go to the interactive shell and run the following

```
>> from app.database import db_session
>> from app.models.product import Product
>> product = Product(name="My Product",price=100)
>> db_session.add(product)
>> db_session.commit()
>> Product.query.all()
```

For some reasons this fails with the error in the beginning. If I restart my interactive shell it would work appropriately. Any clue on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `StaticPool` as it'd maintain a single connection, which might be more suitable for single-thread use (in the shell). [Reference](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior)

```
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool
engine = create_engine(
    'sqlite:////tmp/test.db',
    poolclass=StaticPool,
    connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}
)
```

Comment: :O This solve the issue on my interactive shell. Thanks any reasoning behind this? or docs where I could have told.

Comment: Also why is this failing in my single thread application. Anyone has any pointers on a full explanation of the situation?

Comment: Most likely an outdated version of sqlite

Comment: Also there may be something weird in your imports. I'd make a minimal app which can reproduce the problem and post its code here. Without that its hard to say the exact reason (cause there is nothing wrong in the code you posted)